# How to select based on a certain condition, but I don't want that condition to list in the result

Tags: sql, group-by

I have productnumber, warehouse, onhand qty.
we have 3 warehouse A,B,C. 
How do I select, just by one statement, without having to do temporary table to pull the on hand quantity from warehouse A and B only?
If I put the filter criteria as A,B then those warehouses will be listed in the result, which I don't want. It's easy to do sum total on hand for all warehouse but when it comes to this, I'm kind of confused.

Answer (score 0):

You just want a `where` clause in an aggregation query with no `group by`:

```
select sum(onhandqty)
from tablet
where warehouse in ('A', 'B');
```

You don't give sample data or the layout of the tables, but you should be able to adapt this for your structure.

EDIT:

You can aggregate this by other fields, even ones you don't mention in the question, if the fields are in the data.

```
select product, sum(onhandqty)
from tablet
where warehouse in ('A', 'B')
group by product;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, the issue is I also want to list Product- sum on hand qty, that's why I thought I have to include 'warehouse' there.